# Como atualizar view materializada com REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND

Tags: oracle, view, job

Preciso criar uma view materializada que será atualizada em determinados horários do dia utilizando REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND, como se trata de milhões de registros, a opção ON COMMIT está descartada. Mesmo criando as tabelas de log para as tabelas de origem, a view não está sendo atualizada quando ocorre inserts nas tabelas de origem.

Ao verificar os logs de execução do job, encontro o log a seguir:

“ORA-12004: REFRESH FAST não pode ser utilizado para view materializada “DESV”.”VM_LOG_EMPRESTIMO”
ORA-06512: em “SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA”, line 3012
ORA-06512: em “SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA”, line 2424
ORA-06512: em “SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA”, line 88
ORA-06512: em “SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA”, line 253
ORA-06512: em “SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA”, line 2405
ORA-06512: em “SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA”, line 2968
ORA-06512: em “SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA”, line 3255
ORA-06512: em “SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA”, line 3287
ORA-06512: em “SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT”, line 16
ORA-06512: em “DESV.REFRESH_VM_LOG_EMPRESTIMO”, line 4
”

A seguir, estão todos os códigos:

-- criação da view materializada com a opção refresh force on demand (depois é que altero para fast)

```
create materialized view vm_log_emprestimo
refresh force on demand
as select u.nomeusuario, l.nomelivro, a.nomeautor ,e.dataemprestimo, e.datadevolucao
from usuario u join emprestimo e
on (u.codusuario = e.codusuario) join livro l
on (e.codlivro = l.codlivro) join autor a
on(l.codautor = a.codautor);
```

-- criação das tabelas de log

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW log ON usuario WITH ROWID;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW log ON emprestimo WITH ROWID;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW log ON livro WITH ROWID;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW log ON autor WITH ROWID;
```

-- alteração da view para refresh fast on demand

```
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW vm_log_emprestimo REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND;
```

-- criação da procedure para executar o refresh na view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE refresh_vm_log_emprestimo
AS
BEGIN
    DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('vm_log_emprestimo');
END;
/
```

-- criação do job que vai executar a procedure

```
BEGIN
dbms_scheduler.create_job (
   job_name           =>  'mview_vm_log_emprestimo',
   job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   job_action         =>  'refresh_vm_log_emprestimo',
   start_date         =>  SYSTIMESTAMP,
   end_date           => NULL,
   repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=DAILY; byhour=18,20,22,00',
   enabled            =>  TRUE
);
END;
/
```

Answer (score -3):

será atualizada 1 vez ao dia, conforme o horário definido

create materialized view name_view
refresh force on demand
start with to_date('27-03-2024 02:43:28', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') next sysdate + 1
as
( select * from table );